# Display those employee names which contain pair of vowels

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

i have  a table, name: employees. Table structure(of  ) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" 
   (    "EMP_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "HIRE_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SALARY" NUMBER(8,2), 
    "COMMI_PCT" NUMBER(2,2), 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "DEP_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_SALARY_MIN" CHECK (salary > 0) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_UK" UNIQUE ("EMAIL") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMP_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DEP_ID")
      REFERENCES  "DEPARTMENTS" ("DEPARTMENT_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_ID")
      REFERENCES  "JOBS" ("JOB_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_MANAGER_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGER_ID")
      REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("EMP_ID") ENABLE
   )
```

i want to display those employee names which contain pair of vowels.

i just try it:

```
SELECT EMP_ID,JOB_ID,last_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (last_name, '([aeiou])\1');
```

Comment: This doesn't show any work.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean two vowels consecutively (upper and lower case), you can use:

```
select *
from employees
where regexp_like(last_name,'[aeiouAEIOU]{2}');
```

If you mean just two vowels anywhere you can use:

```
select *
from employees
where regexp_like(last_name,'[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]');
```

If you can't use regex for some reason, you would have to come up with every combination of two vowels and do something like this:

```
select * from employess
where (
     last_name like '%a%a%' 
  or last_name like '%a%e%'
  or last_name like '%a%i%'
  etc...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-regexp method, only because regexp can be a bit cpu-expensive, or for people using pre-regexp Oracle versions.

### Consecutive vowels

```
select
  ...
from
  ...
where
  translate(upper(last_name),'EIOU','AAAA') like '%AA%'
```

### Non-consecutive vowels

```
select
  ...
from
  ...
where
  translate(upper(last_name),'EIOU','AAAA') like '%A%A%'
```